# Can't create aliases when using google directory API

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-workspace, google-directory-api

The code I have is shown below. My problem is that when I am trying to update the 'aliases'-field it will not happen. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

body = { "name":{"familyName": "Aaab", "givenName": "Aaab"}, "password": "test@test", "primaryEmail": "testAAb@aaaa.no", "secondaryEmail": "test@gmail.com", 'aliases': ['testLeader@test.com']}
user_add = service.users().insert(body=body).execute()
```

The user that is created with it's fields:

```
    {'kind': 'admin#directory#user', 'id': '106377021897584806221', 'etag': '"TN30oD80QTVK45AAxvl_wbzs4vs/4WNsaqcVI4y7ARsciDEXH7K8Hh4"', 'primaryEmail': 'testaab@test.no', 'name': {'givenName': 'Aaab', 'familyName': 'Aaab', 'fullName': 'Aaab Aaab'}, 'isAdmin': False, 'isDelegatedAdmin': False, 'lastLoginTime': '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'creationTime': '2018-10-24T16:43:27.000Z', 'agreedToTerms': True, 'suspended': False, 'archived': False, 'changePasswordAtNextLogin': False, 'ipWhitelisted': False, 'emails': [{'address': 'testaab@test.no', 'primary': True}], 'customerId': 'C02dcimb3', 'orgUnitPath': '/', 'isMailboxSetup': True, 'isEnrolledIn2Sv': False, 'isEnforcedIn2Sv': False, 'includeInGlobalAddressList': True}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not happen"? All I see is you creating a dictionary with an `aliases` key value pair?

Comment: the user that is created will not get an aliases-field

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) I do not think `aliases` is a valid field when creating a user.

Comment: Aha, so you'll have to do it manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you cannot specify an alias for a user when creating them in the Google Directory API. As the documentation lists [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) there is no field for `aliases`.

To add an alias to a user there seems to be a different API call used for that. You have to manually insert each alias you want using the `alias.insert` API call as listed [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/insert). It seems all you need is the unique `userKey` as the field to pass in along with alias for the user.

The exact Python documentation for this API call is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.aliases.html#insert).

Example code using this function:

```
body = {"alias": "testLeader@test.com"}
service.users().aliases().insert(userKey=key, body=body).execute()
```